# Magento2 : Reduce time of Product Update API Using REST

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api

I have created an API to update Product Price, Product Cost, and Tier prices. The issue is the API response timing in around 7 to 8 secs every time for a single product update.

How can I reduce this?

Can we implement in API the logic of Default Product import to update product feature as that process is very fast?

Comment: Yes that process will be fast.